# MATLAB: Method for Determining if a Polygon is Intersecting

Tags: matlab, intersection

This is my method for determining if a polygon is intersecting.

1. Find the equations of each side of the polygon and simultaneously solving one for another to determine where they intersect, at which point.

   ```
   %m=[vector of gradients] c=[vector of y intersects]. 
   y = (m_n)x + (c_n)
   x = (y-c) ./ (m-2) %(don't include first value for m and c)
   y = m.*x + c
   ```

(I think you will need a loop?)

2. Then if they intersect this would be entered into a matrix.

   ```
   intersects = [x_1 y_1;...;x_n y_n] %(x_1 = 1st insect on x plane)
   ```
3. If intersects contained values.

   ```
   disp('This polygon is complex')
   ```
4. Then it would involve breaking down the polygon into its subsequent parts and calculating the area for each using the new points.

Could someone let me know if this makes sense?

Would this work:

```
for i=1:length(m)
    x{i} = (m(i)- c)./ (m-c(i));
    y{i} = m.*x{i}+c;
end
```

Comment: why not using `polyxpoly`?

Comment: I need to show that I have developed my own method.

Comment: Your method sounds reasonable with a couple caveats. 1) You probably only need to check each edge against edges that are not its neighbors (parallel neighboring edges are a weird special case). 2) All non-parallel lines intersect. Make sure the intersections are actually on the edges, rather than somewhere else on the infinite lines.

Comment: if i had a vector of gradients: m=[] and a vector of y intercepts: c = [] for every line. How would then I solve each simultaneously against the other. Check my question at the bottom. @Doug

Comment: I think you've pretty much got it. Seem like you should be trying this yourself and debugging your own code at this point.